# Getting hebrew letters from client to server

Tags: c#, c++, unicode, client, ascii

I've recently developed a client server program in which the client runs on C++ and the server runs on C#.  I want to send to the server Hebrew letters mixed with English letters, but when I receive the letters on the server and convert them to Unicode I get gibberish. When I convert them to ASCII I get all the English letters but the Hebrew letters are marked with a "?" , but when I debugged the client I saw that the variable I sent to the server had all the Hebrew and English letters in it.

Client code:

```
void sendData(SOCKET mySocket,const char* s)
{
    int nBytes;
    unsigned long messageSize = strlen(s);

    messageSize = htonl(messageSize);

    if ((nBytes = send(mySocket, (char*)&messageSize, sizeof(messageSize), 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Client: Send Failed Sir!\n";
        int n=WSAGetLastError();
        cout << n << "\n";
    }

    messageSize = ntohl(messageSize);
    if ((nBytes = send(mySocket, s, messageSize, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Client: It wont go through sir!!\n";
    }
}
```

Server code:

```
bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 600);

// maybe some bounds check too
int len = Array.IndexOf(message, (byte)0);
string asString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(message, 0, len);
```

Comment: You probably have to send Hebrew letters from end to beginning...?

Comment: i tried sending only Hebrew letters but as i wrote above i received gibberish when converting to Unicode and "?" when converting to ASCII in the server

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep your server code generic you can send Unicode from the client.
Convert to Unicode via the [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. The Hebrew code page is 1255.

You can call this function via C++/CLI in the server too.